# Newline character serializes to different number of characters depending on submit method?

Tags: jquery

I have a 5-field HTML form, a newline character (pressing enter, %0A) in the field at index 1, all others empty.

If I use

```
$.post( "http://myserver.com/page.php", $("#fields").serialize()
```

and then on page.php call

```
echo serialize( $_POST['fields'] );
```

the result is

```
a:4:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:1:" ";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";}
```

Notice the string length in the index 1 field is 1.

Now if I submit the same form using the regular html submit form button and the same call on page.php the result is

```
a:4:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:" ";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";}
```

Note how now the string length in the index 1 field is 2. Experiments show that it seems to increase the length by one per newline character.

What is the cause of this and how can I make the jquery call match the standard call? Thanks.

Comment: What does Java have to do with it?

Comment: Just guessing, but can it have something to do with the fact that [only 'successful controls' are serialized](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/#entry-longdesc)?

Comment: Everything is being submitted though, just apparently being encoded differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code to fix was

```
$("#fields").serialize().replace(/\%0A/g, "%0D%0A")
```

Answer (score 0):

[from jQuery ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> processData (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, changing the traditional flag does not seem to alter the results I'm getting. Perhaps you could suggest a modification to my example above if you think this could be the cause?